# get text from text view in the widget provider

Tags: android, widget

I have an Android widget which I'm working at. I am in the onReceive() method from a provider class, and I don't know how to get the text of one of my TextViews. I know how to get the text in an activity class (e.g: (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)), but I don't know how to get it inside of a provider class.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969019/retrieve-text-from-textbox-in-android-widget/10969042#10969042